# What is wrong in this if structures?

Tags: ruby

I have the method, which shows me the error :
"syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end". Where i made a mistake ?

```
def clicked(p,u)
        if (Like.where(post_id: p.id).empty?)
            return false
        else 
            posts=Like.where(post_id: p.id)
            if ((posts.length<1) && (posts[0].user_id==u.id) && (posts[0].action!=nil))==true then return true 
            else 
                if ((posts.length<1) && (posts[0].user_id!=u.id))  then return false 
                else posts.each do |i|
                    if (i.user_id==u.id) then return true
                    end
                end
            end
        end
end
```

Comment: It would probably be a lot easier to see what your code structure really is if you pretended that `then` didn't exist and you put the `if`'s body under it rather than hidden way off to the right .

Comment: Try pasting your code into an editor that does auto-indentation, and then tell the editor to auto-indent the code.  That trick reveals the cause of many errors like the one you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`posts.each` should be closed by a `end` keyword

```
def clicked(p,u)
        if (Like.where(post_id: p.id).empty?)
            return false
        else 
            posts=Like.where(post_id: p.id)
            if ((posts.length<1) && (posts[0].user_id==u.id) && (posts[0].action!=nil))==true then return true 
            else 
                if ((posts.length<1) && (posts[0].user_id!=u.id))  then return false 
                else 
                    posts.each do |i|
                        if (i.user_id==u.id) then return true
                        end
                    # The missing end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it easier for you and others to spot problems of this sort, avoid using the "if....then" form of Ruby's *if* statement, especially in conjunction with an "else" clause on a separate line.  Also, avoid putting code on the same line as the "else" keyword.  Instead of this:

```
if some_condition then do_something
else
  do_something_else
end
```

or this:

```
if some_condition
  do_something
else do_something_else
end
```

prefer this:

```
if some_condition
  do_something
else
  do_something_else
end
```

Using these fairly standard formatting practices will make this class of syntax errors much easier to avoid, and easier to debug when they do occur.