# What is wrong in this ruby on rails method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My [syntax error is solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34445997/what-is-wrong-in-this-if-structures), but now I've got another problem.

I have a model User and Post. Also i've created the additional model which is called Like(for likes/dislikes system). So, i wrote a method to check if the copy of the model Like has the given 'post_id' and 'user_id' simulteniously, then the given Post was liked by the given User. Here's the code of my method

```
def licked(p,u)#p - post, u - user
        if Like.all.empty? then return false
        else
            if (Like.where(post_id: p.id).empty?)
                return false
            else 
                posts=Like.where(post_id: p.id)
                if ((posts.length<2) && (posts[0].user_id==u.id) && (posts[0].action!=nil))==true then return true 
                else 
                    if ((posts.length<2) && (posts[0].user_id!=u.id)&& (posts[0].action!=nil))  then return false 
                    else posts.each do |i|


        if (i.user_id==u.id&& (posts[0].action!=nil)) then return true
                    end
                end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Sorry, if there are many if's, i did not find any other way to relize it, and anyway it's not working. So i'm asking for your help: either to hange the existing code or making it other way, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need ANY of that logic.

```
def liked(post, user)
  Like.where(user_id: user.id, post_id: post.id).where.not(action: nil).exists?
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a way easier